# List table sizes for all tables on all databases

Tags: sql-server

Is there a simple way of listing the size of every table in every database on a MSSQL server?

I have used a query on sys.tables to get results for a single database, but we have >100 databases per server, so a way of getting the same results but for all databases would be great.

Currently I'm having to create a temporary list of databases from master.sys.databases, and then iterate over that with a cursor, building a query and inserting the results into a temp table with `EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQLString`.

Comment: Object space information is stored in the database where the object resides. So there is no other way then to iterate using a list of databases. Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @cylindric, a useful link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to get this across all of your environment, for all of your databases...and you don't mind using PowerShell... You will need run this from a machine that at least has SQL Server 2008 Management Studio installed.

```
# Load SMO
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null

function Get-TableSize ([string[]]$server) {
    foreach ($srv in $server) {
        $s = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' $srv

        $s.Databases.Tables | 
            ? {-Not $_.IsSystemObject} | 
                Select @{Label="Server";Expression={$srv}},
                    @{Label="DatabaseName";Expression={$_.Parent}}, 
                    @{Label="TableName";Expression={$_.Name}}, 
                    @{Label="SizeKB";Expression={$_.DataSpaceUsed}}
    }
}
```

As labeled the `DataSpaceUsed` SMO object outputs in "KB", you can modify this to be the measurement of your choice by just putting the abbreviated reference for it. So if I wanted "MB": `$_.DataSpaceUsed/1MB`.

In the function `([string[]]$server)`, the brackets "[]" mean the parameter accepts an array of objects. So if you have your servers listed in a file you can call the function like so:

```
$list = get-content .\ServerList.txt
Get-TableSize -server $list | Out-GridView
```

I prefer using `Out-GridView` initially to review the output, and it copies easily straight into Excel for me. You can also output this to the other supported formats of PowerShell if desired.

Example with screenshot, you can also just list the servers out:
[image]

Comment: This could be pretty perfect. I'll test it out!

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I only had to add authentication, and got the additional fields I needed from the Table object http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Taken from Stack-Overflow: [Get size of all tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database)

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Comment: That's exactly what I already have that doesn't do what I need - that just shows one database.

Answer (score 3):

I used a merge of previous answers:

```
USE [master];
GO

sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
SELECT  
''?'' as db,    
t.NAME AS TableName,    
s.Name AS SchemaName,    
p.rows AS RowCounts,    
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB,     
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB 
FROM     sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN      sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN     sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE    p.rows > 0 AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY     t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows 
ORDER BY p.rows DESC' ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Fer R's answer but combined into a single result set.   The warnings related to sp_MSforeachdb apply.

```
set nocount on

USE [master];
GO

if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp(
    rec_id      int IDENTITY (1, 1),
    db sysname, 
    TableName   varchar(128),
    SchemaName varchar(128),
    RowCounts   bigint,
    TotalSpaceMB    decimal(15,2),  
    UsedSpaceMB decimal(15,2),
    UnusedSpaceMB   decimal(15,2)   )


exec sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
insert into #temp (db, TableName, SchemaName, RowCounts, TotalSpaceMB, UsedSpaceMB, UnusedSpaceMB)
SELECT  
''?'' as db,    
t.NAME AS TableName,    
s.Name AS SchemaName,    
p.rows AS RowCounts,    
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8/1024 AS TotalSpaceMB,     
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8/1024 AS UsedSpaceMB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8/1024 AS UnusedSpaceMB 
FROM     sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN      sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN     sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE    p.rows > 0 AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY     t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows 
ORDER BY p.rows DESC' ;

select db, TableName, SchemaName, RowCounts, TotalSpaceMB, UsedSpaceMB, UnusedSpaceMB
from #temp
order by db, SchemaName, TableName
```

Comment: Much better than the original solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `sp_msforeachdb` however a couple of warnings with this.

- You are using dynamic SQL so it can be a bit tricky
- It is undocumented and unsupported so may change or go away at any version
- [It has some known flaws including problems with snapshots and skipping the odd database](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2012/10/its-time-to-retire-sp_msforeachdb/)

That being said I've used it successfully for several years now.

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT * FROM sys.tables'
```

Basically it does a cursor and a replace on the ? with the DB name.

[You could also try Aaron Bertrand's replacement version.](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)  I haven't tried it out myself but it is supposed to be better.

Answer (score 0):

The following will solve your question:

```
use master
DECLARE @xQry NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SELECT @xQry+= ' UNION ALL SELECT '''+name+''' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS AS [Database], 
    schema_name(tab.schema_id) + ''.'' + tab.name COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS AS [table], 
        cast(sum(spc.used_pages * 8)/1024.00 as numeric(36, 2)) as used_mb,
        cast(sum(spc.total_pages * 8)/1024.00 as numeric(36, 2)) as allocated_mb
    from '+name+'.sys.tables tab
    join '+name+'.sys.indexes ind 
         on tab.object_id = ind.object_id
    join '+name+'.sys.partitions part 
         on ind.object_id = part.object_id and ind.index_id = part.index_id
    join '+name+'.sys.allocation_units spc
         on part.partition_id = spc.container_id
    group by schema_name(tab.schema_id) + ''.'' + tab.name COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS'
FROM sys.databases 

SET @xQry= RIGHT(@xQry,LEN(@xQry)-11) + ' order by 3 desc'
EXEC (@xQry)
```